# red5 published flv every time looks corrupted

Tags: video-streaming, red5

I use red5 and flex.
After publishing the stream, it creates flv file that plays in flv players like corrupted one.
It looks like this http://screencast.com/t/gkqQWqhcYT

Answer (score 2):

There is a bug for Red5 0.9.1: http://code.google.com/p/red5/issues/detail?id=42.

**Edit**:

It seems to be fixed since August 10th 2012: http://code.google.com/p/red5/issues/detail?id=42#c8, but I don't work with Red5 anymore, so I really don't know a lot about this fix.

Comment: Thanks! I opened a topic for it: [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12845920/red5-video-stream-recording-is-breaking-up)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry your screencast does not work at all.

Also the description is rather general. It could apply to 1000 different implementations.
However would help if the screencast would work.

In general you should always playback the stream in the resolution that you recorded it. Everything else will look ugly.
And yes: You always should try to use the latest revision, compiling Red5 from Source is really not that tricky.

Sebastian