# Red5 video stream recording is breaking up

Tags: java, video, stream, red5

Finally I created a stream video recorder flash application and its simple Red5 backend but of course Red5 jokes me again. Most of the times the recorded videos are corrupted, cannot play them back without randomly stopping-resuming, hanging out the player .. and me as well. Why is it doing this?

I researched the internet and found this issue but no solution! I tried not to record the video instead switch it to live and attach an ffmpeg to do the dirty job but naturally the ffmpeg couldn't connect with the following error message on the red5's output:

> Error executing call: Service: null Method: play Num Params: 1 0: my_little_stream ... blabla bla

Before I try out integrating the [Xuggler](http://www.xuggle.com/xuggler) stuff what I truly don't want to I ask you, what to do, can I attach the ffmpeg somehow or is there a configuration in the red5 server I should change.. or anything! Thanks!

**Edit**: I'm using Red5 1.0 RC2

**Edit#2**: I compiled the oflaDemo app from trunk sources with red5 1.0.0rc2 server files then created a live stream with a simple flex app just to try out if ffmpeg recorder worked. Now it could connect to red5 but the result is the same! The videos seems to be corrupt...

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/red5/issues/detail?id=42#c8 says this bug to be fixed, but I don't know a lot about it.

Comment: were you able to fix this? I am having the exact same problem, and followed all the steps you went through (with seba.wagner) with no fix!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*But what should I put into the packetReceived() function? *

I add this in a separated answer to highlight correctly:

To write the packets to disk, you need:
1) the packet,
2) convert the packet to an ITag
3) Obtain an instance of a ITagWriter

1) the packet data 
http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/incubator/openmeetings/trunk/singlewebapp/src/org/apache/openmeetings/data/flvrecord/listener/StreamVideoListener.java?view=markup 
around Line 50

```
public void packetReceived(IBroadcastStream broadcastStream,
  IStreamPacket streampacket) {

}
```

streampacket => the packet you want to write to disk.

2) write the packet by converting it to a ITag

http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/incubator/openmeetings/trunk/singlewebapp/src/org/apache/openmeetings/data/flvrecord/listener/async/StreamVideoWriter.java?view=markup
around Line 90ff

```
        IoBuffer data = streampacket.getData().asReadOnlyBuffer();

        if (data.limit() == 0) {
            return;
        }

        if (startTimeStamp == -1) {
            // That will be not bigger then long value
            startTimeStamp = streampacket.getTimestamp();
        }

        timeStamp -= startTimeStamp;

        ITag tag = new Tag();
        tag.setDataType(streampacket.getDataType());

        // log.debug("data.limit() :: "+data.limit());
        tag.setBodySize(data.limit());
        tag.setTimestamp(timeStamp);
        tag.setBody(data);

        writer.writeTag(tag);
```

3) Obtaining an instance of a Writer

http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/incubator/openmeetings/trunk/singlewebapp/src/org/apache/openmeetings/data/flvrecord/listener/async/BaseStreamWriter.java?view=markup 
around Line 90ff

```
protected ITagWriter writer = null;

private void init() throws IOException {
    file = new File(OmFileHelper.getStreamsSubDir(this.scope.getName()), this.streamName + ".flv");

    IStreamableFileFactory factory = (IStreamableFileFactory) ScopeUtils
            .getScopeService(this.scope, IStreamableFileFactory.class,
                    StreamableFileFactory.class);

    if (!this.file.isFile()) {
        // Maybe the (previously existing) file has been deleted
        this.file.createNewFile();

    } else if (!file.canWrite()) {
        throw new IOException("The file is read-only");
    }

    IStreamableFileService service = factory.getService(this.file);
    IStreamableFile flv = service.getStreamableFile(this.file);
    this.writer = flv.getWriter();

}
```

So this is a rough walk through. In that sense you can then go ahead.

The 
http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/incubator/openmeetings/trunk/singlewebapp/src/org/apache/openmeetings/data/flvrecord/listener/async/BaseStreamWriter.java?view=markup

class also contains a Queue to collect the packets.

IStreamPacket.getType == 9 is video and I think 8 is audio (but you need to verify that).

Sebastian

Comment: Okay, that works fine! I made it based on your instructions and the flvrecord package.

Comment: Make sure you keep an eye on the timestamp of the packets. The issue can be that the timestamps are wrong when somebody has bandwidth issues. You might check recorded FLVs simply with VNC viewer.

Comment: Can I have some more instructions about it? Basically I copied the listener and writer classes and cut out the Dao and other database related stuffs. And switched to the FilenameGenerator bean to generate the filenames.

Comment: The timestamps are relative to the beginning of the recording. So when you press "start" then the timestamp should start to count with zero. I think important is just that you start to count when the user presses "start" and not when the first packets actually arrive, cause in case that there are bandwidth issues the packets might arrive never or very later. So just count start by zero is important.

Comment: One more question!:) Is it okay if the listener.closeStream() stops its writer but in fact it stops about after a half min?

Comment: I don't understand that. In fact it should be quite the opposite way round. Cause: As you did face already: Writing the packets to disk is _more_ slowly then receiving packets. That is why your red5 app did slow down => packets need to be written to disk. Now: If you call "stop" actually the packet writer should be still busy with writing packets to the disk. You should not stop it, you should wait until all packets are written. Otherwise the effect will be that there might be missing 5-20 seconds at the end of every recording.

Comment: Okay, it's clear now! I was trying it on a high traffic, slow server, and the multi-threaded flv writing method showed its advantage! But the other issue is still active, playing the videos breaking up, sometimes the player (VLC as well) cannot play them properly, the video freezes for a while, breaking up, etc. Not stable. What else could I check out?

Comment: you could try to convert the video using FFMPEG to something else. Maybe the videos just have no good settings. But it can also be that the user had bandwidth issues while recording. That means some frames are dropped. That looks like the video freezes for a while and then continues.

Comment: I tried FFMPEG but the way I did it resulted the same. This issue is on localhost as well. Is there any option to force the keyframes or something? I tried manipulating with the keyframes but no success.:(

Comment: This issue occurs mostly the beginning of the video.

Comment: that can happen because you did not catch all the video frames. You know: It is streaming. So if you attach a stream listener it will only catch the current packets. The image in the video that you see will not send the complete image always, it devides the screen in xx number of tiles and only sends the ones that changes. If you attach your recorder, you have to force the NetStream to send a complete refresh of the whole image. I have seen some code somewhere doing that but you might try to investigate in that direction.

Comment: Ok, that's clear now, thanks! I'm going to do some research now, but can you give me some idea?

Comment: Is this a client or a server side issue? How did you solve this? Should I open a new question for this?

Comment: There might be a NetStream Status Event that could provoke to produce a "keyframe". There might be also a way to simulate this event in the client. But I can't tell you how. You should open a new question, for example with some subject like like: "How to force the NetStream to create a keyframe" and with the description of your problem.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13601078/how-to-force-the-netstream-to-create-a-keyframe

Answer (score 0):

What recording method do you use now?
There are actually 2 methods in Red5 to record:
1) NetStream.record => this is plain simple
2) You do NetStream "live" but you have a server side StreamListener that you attach to the stream and then write the stream to disc.

I have implemented both solutions successfully at: http://incubator.apache.org/openmeetings/
There is no choppy video or random stop/pause.

There is no need to integrate FFMPEG or Xuggler to do a simple recording with Red5! FFMPEG might be useful if you want to modify the resulting video and add a watermark.
For audio editing you might use tools like SoX. However ... just plain record and playback as-is does not require those tools at all!

Sebastian

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but could you tell me more about the second solution? Isn't it similar to that I'm trying with ffmpeg by attaching it to a live stream?

Comment: No ,not at all. The second solution is described for example here http://sziebert.net/posts/server-side-stream-recording-with-red5/

Comment: I modified my app as the second method. I think it didn't solve the problem and there is another one, maybe that is the root of this one. [another topic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12893159/red5-communication-delay) Could you check it out?

Comment: Could you check it out => I've posted the solution that we made to solve the performance issue in server side recording

Comment: Ok, now I'm beginning to understand..:) I've created a StreamLinstener and added it to the stream. But what should I put into the packetReceived() function? I've found some example codes but they are too complex I cannot understand them..