# How to force the NetStream to create a keyframe?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, video-streaming, flv

I created a video stream recording application that works fine except the recorded FLVs are corrupt a little bit. :) If I open an FLV in VLC player everything is green but getting "clean" when changes occur. And especially at the beginning of the video is breaking up. (I use Red5 1.0)

Comment: this question is actually not red5 specific. You might have the same problem with Flash Media Server. It might be a simple ActionScript3 issue.

Comment: I see you deleted your question about Google Drive. If you have some code but it hasn't worked, then post that question along with the code. That will ensure people see that you've made a prior effort, which is why you were downvoted.

Comment: Okay, thanks! I will do it.

Answer (score 1):

For pre-recorded streams, the keyframes are already encoded into the file and they cannot be changed. If you're serving a live stream, the keyframes need to be set in the application that is encoding the live stream (for example, Flash Media Live Encoder).

Comment: And in case you want to set the keyframe interval in Actionscript, use: `Camera.setKeyFrameInterval()`

Comment: The way I do it is the client records a video with its camera over a stream. The result is a buggy FLV video. How to force the client to send the keyframe at the very beginning of the stream?

Comment: And of course I tried `setKeyFrameInterval` but no success. :(

Comment: The "green" problem is a common one. Perhaps the problem is not keyframe related. What size are you encoding at?