# red5 0.8 application for recording

Tags: red5

where i can download application for recording in red5 0.8. I use 0.8 version because 1.0.1 have a problem, e.g. if i record a new stream for 60 seconds
recorded file is about 40 seconds.

Tnx

Answer (score 0):

The question is what you are using to "record". 
There are different ways, either client based with NetStream.publish("stramname", "record") or server side stream recording.
But using Red5 0.8 will not improve the recording at all, not matter what type of recording functionality you are using.
The server side recording is more complicated but it creates by far the better quality of videos as you have more control about the recording process.
So if you have some Java background you should do that. I have discussed that recently with another user quite extended at: [Red5 video stream recording is breaking up](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12845920/1448704)

Sebastian

Answer (score 0):

For recording check out this patched Red5 1.0.2 available at: [Recording high quality (HD) video over slow connections with Red5 is now possible](http://nusofthq.com/blog/recording-high-quality-hd-video-over-slow-connections-with-red5-is-now-possible/)

[The patch has also been applied to Red5's source code on GitHub](https://github.com/Red5/red5-server/commit/7e4253f577a88d50613900986a46e5a915859123) and it will be included with the next official build(1.0.3).

I am the author of that patch and I made it to fix the delayed write recording mechanism Red5. It works great, we're using it for our [HD video recording demo](http://hdfvr.com/demo/hdlauncher) where you can check out how it works.